# Vertex relative distance locking

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertex-groups

As in the title i want to lock the distance between a group of vertices so when i edit the object they won't move in the group but be able to move as a group.

Those are the vertices.
[image]

Can it be done?

Comment: I don't *think* so, but I might be wrong.

Comment: As a workaround you could duplicate that vertices, separate them as new object, then hook all the original vertices to the new object, then transform the new object... the hook will move all original vertices as a whole; but they are still not locked, thats not (yet) possible.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that it's possible to actually lock vertices. I can think of a workaround though.

Select the vertices you want locked **in vertex select mode**, and press <kbd>H</kbd>. This will hides them, so you won't be able to move them around.

When you're done, and you want to bring them back (unlock them) just press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>